# Getting google document onto Wordpress post editor

Tags: php, wordpress, google-docs-api

I have a wordpresss blog where i post a lot of stuffs. Sometimes a few people do write contents for me. They usually write it on google docs and they send me a link.
I would like to write a small plugin whereby on each post there is an option to input the google doc link for an article and pressing a button brings the post onto the wordpress editor.
I much confused about how to proceed with the google docs api part? what is the easiest way to achieve the import ?

Answer (score 1):

Try [docs-to-wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/docs-to-wordpress/)

This plugin will grab docs out of a collection in Google Docs, create or update a post in WordPress and then move the doc to a new collection. Google Docs no longer supports xmlrpc, so this is perhaps the easiest way to move content from your Google Docs account to your self-hosted WordPress install.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Google script that will convert a Google Doc to a nice clean html email, that you can copy and paste in a Wordpress editor.

http://omaralzabir.com/googledocs2cleanhtml/

Hope this helps. I have been looking for a solution for a long time. Finally, had to spend some time and make one for myself, as I use Google Docs for authoring my blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

My company just released this [Google Drive app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs-to-wordpress/nbljnjmeckdecofjohdobgmleppiikll/related). It automatically uploads your Google document to WordPress, including all your images. It also adjusts all the formatting to fit your blog's theme.